# run cucumber multiple tags in node.js

Tags: node.js, tags, cucumber, gherkin

I have created one feature with three scenarios, each scenario has a tag.
Feature: Three scenarios

@Scenario1
Scenario ...
Given ....
When ...
Then ...

@Scenario2
Scenario ...
Given ....
When ...
Then ...

@Scenario3
Scenario ...
Given ....
When ...
Then ...

When I run just with a tag, it is working.
command contains: ... --tags @Scenario1

When I tried with two tags, it is not working.
The following commands I tried:

1. ... --tags={"@Scenario1","@Scenario2"}
2. ... --tags={'@Scenario1','@Scenario2'}
3. ... --tags={@Scenario1,@Scenario2}
4. ... --tags={"@Scenario1,@Scenario2"}
5. ... --tags={"@Scenario1 and @Scenario2"}
6. ... --tags "@Scenario1 and @Scenario2"
7. ... --tags @Scenario1 --tags @Scenario2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `--tags "@Scenario1 or @Scenario2"`. See [Tag Expressions](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions) for details.

You can also run scenarios by line: `cucumber features/hello.feature:34:48`

Answer (score -1):

try `--tags @Scenario1 , @Scenario2`

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: This doesn't work. Reference the valid answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64178319/5560215